# htaccess mod rewrite urls wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite some URLs using the htaccess file.

i believe this is what i want to use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^villa_rental_italy/([^/]*)$ /villa_rental_italy?region=$1&search=region [L]
```

to get urls like this:

/villa_rental_italy?region=regions-veneto&search=region

to look like this:

/villa_rental_italy/regions-veneto

I have added the rewrite to htaccess, and i get page-not-found when i try the new URL (/villa_rental_italy/regions-veneto)

htaccess file:

```html
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^villa_rental_italy/([^/]*)$ /villa_rental_italy?region=$1&search=region [L]

</IfModule>



# END WordPress
```

note* i have tried adding the new rewrite rule at the top of the file, where it is and below at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RewriteRule` is never reached, due to the previous `RewriteRule`. Move the `RewriteRule` up a few lines, before this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hiya, thank you for your super quick reply, just tried it and it still doesnt work. Still page not found when i try the new link. thanks Sam

Comment: Remove the `[L]` from the `villa_rental_italy` RewriteRule. This makes sure the next RewriteRule (rewrite to index.php) is applied as well.

Comment: Hello, thanks again, i removed the L and still page not found. any more ideas?

Comment: Debug every step. First test what happens if you request the rewritten url directly (within your browser). If that works, test what input data your script receives (`phpinfo()` on the *page not found* page or by using xdebug). You can also temporarily add a `[R,L]` after the `RewriteRule` to check the rewritten url in your browser.

Comment: Thank you Pieter, adding the [r,l] works, but am unable to test the phpinfo, its not my strong point at all.